# Actively change language of a GUI in PyQt5

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, worker

I'm working on multithread PyQt5 application.
Now I want to convert it to append multi language support, using two puss buttons, which might dynamically change bunch of labels (images and texts).

I wrote a simpler code below, merely to demonstrate my problem. I already know that I should add `setText()` in `btn1_onClicked()` and `btn2_onClicked()` functions to make it work though. But I'm barely looking for any alternative way to do it without changing `onClicked` functions. Because in my main script, texts are sent via `pyqtsignal` in an Infinite while loop (implemented in a worker thread).

Hence, I really appreciate if one can help me do it without changing `btn1_onClicked()` and `btn2_onClicked()` functions.

Thanks

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel

hello_en = 'Hello'
hello_fr = 'bonjour'

class MultiButtons(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call parent constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.lang = 'en'

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('English', self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(130, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Francias', self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(200, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_onClicked)

        self.msgLabel = QLabel('', self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(130, 120, 300, 80)

        self.setWindowTitle('Use of multiple PushButtons')
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
        self.msgLabel.setText(F"{hello_en if (self.lang == 'en') else hello_fr}")

        self.move(850, 300)
        self.show()

    def btn1_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'en'

    def btn2_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'fr'

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = MultiButtons()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use buttons and don't want to change your onClicked functions you could connect another function after your calls to your onClicked functions, like below:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel

hello_en = 'Hello'
hello_fr = 'bonjour'

class MultiButtons(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call parent constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.lang = 'en'

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('English', self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(130, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.set_language_texts)

        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Francias', self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(200, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_onClicked)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.set_language_texts)

        self.msgLabel = QLabel('', self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(130, 120, 300, 80)

        self.setWindowTitle('Use of multiple PushButtons')
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
        self.msgLabel.setText(F"{hello_en if (self.lang == 'en') else hello_fr}")

        self.move(850, 300)
        self.show()

    def btn1_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'en'

    def btn2_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'fr'

    def set_language_texts(self):
        self.msgLabel.setText(F"{hello_en if (self.lang == 'en') else hello_fr}")
            

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = MultiButtons()
app.exec()
```

If you wanted to add quite a few languages, i'd recommend adding a comboxbox to switch and then have a bunch of lists stored (or set the lists from another class if strings aren't being stored locally) with the different label versions/images you would want to change. Something like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
import sys
class ComboBoxLanguages(QWidget):
    languageStrings = ["English", "French", "German", "Quenya"]
    label1Strings = ["Hello", "Bonjour", "Hallo", "Namárië"]
    label2Strings = ["Farewell", "Bon Voyage", "Auf Wiedersehen", "Navaer"]
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lang = self.languageStrings[0]

        self.combobox1 = QComboBox(self)
        self.combobox1.setGeometry(130, 70, 60, 40)
        [self.combobox1.addItem(lang) for lang in self.languageStrings]
        self.combobox1.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed)
        
        self.msgLabel = QLabel(self.label1Strings[0], self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(130, 120, 300, 80)
        
        self.msg2Label = QLabel(self.label2Strings[0], self)
        self.msg2Label.setGeometry(230, 120, 300, 80)

        self.setWindowTitle('Combobox Language Example')
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 200)
       
        self.move(850, 300)
        self.show()

    def on_combobox_changed(self, value):
        self.lang = value
        languageIndex = self.languageStrings.index(value)
        self.msgLabel.setText(self.label1Strings[languageIndex])
        self.msg2Label.setText(self.label2Strings[languageIndex])
            
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = ComboBoxLanguages()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found something, but I'm not sure if it is a standard way.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel

hello_en = 'Hello'
hello = 'bonjour'

def get_variable_name(variable):
    globals_dict = globals()
    return [var_name for var_name in globals_dict if globals_dict[var_name] is variable]

class MultiButtons(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # Call parent constructor
        super().__init__()
        self.lang = 'en'

        self.btn1 = QPushButton('English', self)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(130, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.btn1_onClicked)
        

        self.btn2 = QPushButton('Francias', self)
        self.btn2.setGeometry(200, 70, 60, 40)
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(self.btn2_onClicked)

        self.msgLabel = QLabel('', self)
        self.msgLabel.setGeometry(130, 120, 300, 80)

        self.setWindowTitle('Use of multiple PushButtons')
        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 500, 200)
        self.SET_Text(hello)

        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda : self.SET_Text(hello))
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda : self.SET_Text(hello))
        

        self.move(850, 300)
        self.show()

    def btn1_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'en'

    def btn2_onClicked(self):
        self.lang = 'fa'

    def SET_Text(self,s):
        if self.lang == 'fa':
            txt = globals()[get_variable_name(s)[0]]
        elif self.lang == 'en':
            txt = globals()[get_variable_name(s)[0]+'_en']
        self.msgLabel.setText(txt)
        
    
    

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
button = MultiButtons()
app.exec()
```

Comment: How many labels are you looking to implement, if it's only a couple then this way is fine. But if you're planning on quite a few it may be better to manage your strings in a different way.

Comment: It's 5 labels. So I continue to do this for my code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).